# GTX 580 graphics card where do the PSU cables go?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, gpu

I currently have 1 pci-e cable plugged into my graphics card but I'm getting 1 long beep and 3 short do I need to plug something into the 8 pin also?

My graphics card is a GTX 580 Gainward Good.

The manual says plug the 6-pin (or 8-pin) PCI Express power cable from your computer's power supply to the extra power connector on the back of the graphics card (pictured) but there is no connection on the back of the graphics card both are on top a 8 pin and a 6 pin.

My PSU is a Corsair 850w

It has one 8 pin for the motherboard, there is an adapter here that converts 2 pci-e into an 8 pin do I need to use that?

FIXED: Takes two PCI-E cables into the GPU not one.

Comment: What does the manual say?

Comment: It looks like they are on the top right (if looking at the side with the plastic cover) and there might be an additional one on the board side, which should be fairly easy to pick out.

Answer (score 4):

Every power plug your graphics card has will need a power cable attached to it.  Without knowing the specific card and it's layout, it's difficult to offer more.

Comment: It requires the use of one 6-pin auxiliary power connector, and one 8-pin auxiliary power connector. It also needs a PSU capable of supplying at least 600W.